# SQL - multiple rows in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

ok, So the query I would like to solve:

I would like to express the following business rule:

Display the groups (for a particular tutorial (tutorialID) and week (week)) that require additional reviews.

So basically I need to determine the amount of members in a group, I then need to aggregate all the scrum reviews for that week and that group, and see if this amount equals the amount of members in the group. If it does, this means that all members have been reviewed for that week, and therefore does not need to be displayed.

Assumptions: a member can only be reviews once per week.

I've tried the following SQL, however I get the following error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

```
SELECT groupName, g.groupId
FROM `student` s, `group` g
WHERE s.GroupId = g.GroupId 
AND s.GroupId IS NOT NULL
AND s.tutorialId =  2
GROUP by s.GroupId
AND s.GroupID = (
    SELECT GroupId
    FROM student
    GROUP BY GroupId
    HAVING  count(*)> (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM scrumreview r, student s
        WHERE r.reviewee = s.studentID
        GROUP BY GroupId    
        AND r.week = 5
        )
    )
```

Student
[image]

scrumreview
[image: enter asdasddescription here]

group
[image]

Comment: added in a Group By in the inner most sub query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner query (starting on line 8) returns multiple `groupid`s. The equality operator `=` compares 1-to-1, but what you want is to compare 1-to-many, which you can do with `IN`.

So, to fix this, on line 7 change the code from this...

```
AND s.GroupID = (
```

...to this:

```
AND s.GroupID IN (
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GroupId
FROM student
GROUP BY GroupId
HAVING  count(*)> (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM scrumreview r, student s
    WHERE r.reviewee = s.studentID  
    AND r.week = 5
    )
```

Returns more than 1 row, either you need to refine that SQL so that it only returns one row, or you need to change the following line:

```
AND s.GroupID = (
```

To an IN:

```
AND s.GroupID IN (
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT groupName, 
g.groupId FROM `student` s, 
`group` g WHERE s.GroupId = g.GroupId  
AND s.GroupId IS NOT NULL 
AND s.tutorialId =  2 
GROUP by s.GroupId AND s.GroupID in (SELECT GroupId FROM student GROUP BY GroupId 
HAVING  count(*)> (SELECT count(*) FROM scrumreview r, student s WHERE r.reviewee =
s.studentID AND r.week = 5))
```